# I am not sure why it's giving this error. Remove duplicate records in Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

```
Select 
    *
from  [myTable]
WHERE  [myTable].ID IN
(
    Select 
        Min( [myTable].ID ),  
        [myTable].Username
FROM [myTable]
group by [myTable].Username);
```

Gives me the error:

> You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the Select statement of the subquery to request only one field

I have duplicate records in Username, so I am trying to eliminate them by using MIN of ID number as the first record in Username is correct. Can someone help or tell me where to look?

```
+------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
| Data |  id   | Fname |  Lname  |   Status     |
+------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
|    1 | 12345 | Kunal | Kumar   | completed    |
|    2 | 12345 | Kunal | Kumar   | Not Started  |
|    3 | 12346 | Rahul | Malviya | Completed    |
|    4 | 12346 | Rahul | Malviya | Not Started  |
+------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: still need the expected output

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I guess in Inner query we should not use the Username column, after removing that, the query is working fine. Thanks Juan

Comment: remember accept the answer if solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you try to compare ID with a touple `{Username, ID}`

Instead you use outer value as filter for inner query.

```
SELECT *
FROM [myTable] T1
WHERE  T1.ID =
     (SELECT Min( T2.ID )
      FROM [myTable] T2
      WHERE T2.Username = T1.Username);
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, I have only Single Table.

Comment: I am using Access to removes duplicates from primary key. I only have one Table named T1. I see you have performed a join on two tables. I only have T1, so how should I execute the sub query?

Comment: I only use one table  `[myTable]`, but assign different alias t1 and t2 so I could use the result of the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I executed your query, but it only returns one record, I need all the records in Username which are unique. That's why I wanted to use group by, which will have 2 records per username and then Min function will pickup the one with lowest ID and the duplicates will be removed. So can we use group by inside Sub query and in the Outer query we can have * to select all columns. Is it more clear now? thanks

Comment: Isnt clear, please show me one example with real data

Comment: Sure, Here is the Sample Data                                                                       id        Username      Fname          Lname                  Status                          1         12345             Kunal           Kumar                 completed                      2         12345             Kunal           Kumar                 Not Started                    3         12346             Rahul           Malviya               Completed                               4         12346             Rahul           Malviya               Not Started

Comment: please add it to the question in a format we can read, remember sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
    *
from  [myTable]
WHERE  [myTable].ID IN
(
    Select 
        Min( [myTable].ID ) 
FROM [myTable]
group by [myTable].Username);
```

I don't know much about MS Access but does it require a column to be selected before you can use it in GROUP BY?

Comment: Thanks a lot Corid, it really worked well and I am very thankful to you. Cheers!